# Restarted phone, now xCode won't recognize it

Tags: iphone, xcode

Has anyone turned off their iphone, then turned it on again only to find that xCode won't recognize it anymore? I'm using xCode 4.6 to run my app with the 6.1 SDK on my iPhone5 which runs iOS7.0.1, and it was working fine up until I turned off my phone. Now, in the organizer I'm getting an orange dot next to my device and it's saying:

> The version of iOS on  is not supported by this
>   installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of
>   the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK;
>   which is available here.

I've tried deleting the app, restarting the phone, cleaning, deleting derived data, deleting the actual derived data folders, unplugging / replugging the phone, and nothing seems to fix this. Has anyone ran into this before and been able to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have xCode5 installed on my computer as well, so I closed xCode4.6, opened xCode5, and it was able to detect my phone and install the app on it. Then I closed xCode5, reopened xCode4.6, and all of a sudden it was also able to detect my phone. Don't know why that works, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not meaning to be rude, but did you read the actual error message you posted? This line:

```
The version of iOS on is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK
Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below
```

means that your phone is not the same as the ios sdk you are using, which is ios 6.1. Your phone is 7.0.1, which aren't the same in any way. So you need to change back to 6.1 on your phone, or use xcode 5 for ios 7 purposes.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But did you read what I wrote? "it was working fine up until I turned off my phone". You should be able to run apps compiled with the 6.1 SDK on iOS7, I've been doing it for the past couple of weeks. And I've submitted apps compiled with 6.1 and Apple has accept them.

Comment: when running the apps, are you running the apps through xcode, or do you have to archive them and load them through iTunes?

Comment: I was running them through xCode. I'm pretty sure this is a glitch because I think the same thing happened to me previously, just can't remember what I did to fix it.

Comment: have you restarted xcode? removed your phone from xcode, and re-added it? sometimes it deals with connections

Comment: Yeah I've done all of that, removed it from the organizer, then plugged it in again.

Comment: if you're able to get xcode 5, get that. Otherwise, try getting iOS 6.1 onto your phone or use the 6.1 simulator maybe

Comment: Actually do have xCode5 and I just ran it, it obviously was able to detect my phone and run my app on my phone. Then I closed it, reopened 4.6.2 and now it recognizes the phone. I guess xCode5 did something that made xCode4.6 recognize it. Thanks for spending the time trying to help me out.

Comment: no problem, glad I could help you out :) but yes, when you have multiple versions of Xcode, i think they somehow like connect or something, idk, but I had that happen to me at one time..